# How can I in Qt C++ parse per TCP received XML structure without to save it in a file?

Tags: xml, qt, tcp, xml-parsing

How can I in Qt C++ parse per TCP received XML structure without to save it in a file? The most example in internet show how to parse XML from the file but none of them shows how to parse XML from a QString :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qt's own XML classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xml-dom-tml.html) can do this. You can give the content to [QDomDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html#setContent-2) as a QString.

Answer (score 1):

There is a class specifically designed for reading from a [QIODevice](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html) or a [QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbytearray.html). Since [QTCPSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtcpsocket.html) and [QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfile.html) are both QIODevices, you can write your parser once and use it for both network connectons and for files.

Go and look at the documentation for the [QXmlStreamReader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qxmlstreamreader.html) to see how to use it properly.